# Cannot put an element on the top Footer

Tags: magento2, blocks, widgets

Dear Magento developers,

Currently I am trying to put an element block on the top of Footer, here is my wanted result:

[image]

Here is my default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
    <block class="Senheng\Def\Block\Html\Subscribe"
        name="mojambe.footer.top"
        template="Senheng_Default::html/footer/subscribe.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

unfortunately nothing is showing up on the home page:

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi everyone, my bad, I just realized that my path is wrong, it should be "Senheng_Default::html/subscribe.phtml'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Senheng\Def\Block\Html\Subscribe"
        name="mojambe.footer.top"
        template="Senheng_Default::html/footer/subscribe.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Run the caching, deploy and upgrade commadn and then check.

Comment: Hi mate, thank for response, I just realized that my path is wrong, it should be "Senheng_Default::html/subscribe.phtml'